# Chrome mobile emulator for Selenium testing- can't use all devices

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, mobile, emulation

I'm doing Selenium JAVA tests for mobile using the Chrome driver with its emulator. The problem is that I can't use the most advanced mobile devices like iPhone 7,8 etc even-though its in my drop-down list when manually testing in the devtools. 
This is the driver init. that works perfectly with many mobile devices:

```
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("mobileIPhone6")){
          Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
          mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
          String exePathChromeDriver = Consts.chromeDriverPath;
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePathChromeDriver);
          PropertyLoader.loadCapabilities();
          ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
          chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
          driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

BUT, When I change line 3 to "iPhone 7" I'm getting this error:

```
2018-03-16 21:25:49 INFO  LogLog4j:210 - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: cannot parse mobileEmulation
from unknown error: 'iPhone 7' must be a valid device
from unknown error: must be a valid device
```

Any idea why? many thanks

Comment: I think the issue is that chromedriver doesn't have support for iPhone 7.

You can look [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/) for the list of emulated devices, and [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/module.json) for the device preset names.

Comment: Thanks! I've reached before to the 2nd link you provided, and I see there is __"title": "iPhone 6/7/8", and also for iPhone X...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well, not sure what its about. The one for `iPhone 6/7/8 Plus` has `iPhone6Plus-landscape.svg` as its image, so maybe its just there as placeholder?

Comment: Thanks! that's explains alot. But still, I'm confused. I've reached before to the 2nd link you provided, and I saw there are "title": "iPhone 6/7/8", and also for iPhone X and more...so what is that means? it lists here all the devices. even the new ones

Comment: mmm...placeholder might be the reason. well Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Wait, I don't think what you wrote about the first link is correct, because I CAN use "Galaxy S5" which is not on that list.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure. I can't find documentation on this so a lot of it is just presumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution and it is now working properly. I had to set the Device Metrics object first:

```
...else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iPhone678")){
      String exePathChromeDriver = Consts.chromeDriverPath;
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePathChromeDriver);

      Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
      deviceMetrics.put("width", 375);
      deviceMetrics.put("height", 667);
      deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 2.0);

      Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
      mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
      mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1");

      ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
      driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Dimension](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Dimension.html) class?

Define an enum EmulatedDevices and use following style:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(EmulatedDevices.IPHONE7.getWidth(),EmulatedDevices.IPHONE7.getHeight()));
```

Comment: How will it help? is it only for the size of the screen? (I mean, is this the only configuration change that the emulator gives us, the screen size?)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone 6");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the devices mentioned in the 'Emulated Devices' list within Chrome devtools > Devices. If the desired device is not present within the list you can 'Add custom device' ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crg4r.png))- providing basic information, and use the `deviceName` within your code. In another way, you can directly provide your desired device's basic information (`width, height, pixelRatio`) within your automation code to use that device for testing. You can get the details code with explanation [here](https://youtu.be/UOwEcGr3P9A).