# How to set browser width to minimum using Selenium on Java?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to reduce browser width, but seems browser reached its minimum. Is it possible to reduce width even more?

```
    public void openMobilePage(String url) {
    LOGGER.info("Opening page by URL: " + url);

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }

    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone X");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    WebDriver mobileDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    ChromeOptions capabilities = new ChromeOptions();

    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", "disable-extensions");
    capabilities.addArguments("--hide-scrollbars");
    capabilities.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
    capabilities.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    capabilities.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

    mobileDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(300, 940));

    mobileDriver.get(url);
}
```

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As about the supported screen sizes I see these sizes are supported:

```
mobileDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(340, 695));
```

And

```
mobileDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(480, 320));
```

Also I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056018/chrome-mobile-emulation-window-size-is-different-via-selenium-and-devtools) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394142/emulating-mobile-in-chromedriver) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328454/chrome-mobile-emulator-for-selenium-testing-cant-use-all-devices) explanations how to emulate mobile devise with Selenium.
I hope this will answer your question.